# How to use @QueryInit to init path to attribute of embedded object in QueryDSL query?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, dynamic-queries

According to the QueryDSL docs, (http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.8/reference/html_single/#d0e2250) only the first two levels of paths are initialized in generated Q classes, so if an object A has a relationship inside a `@Entity` B defined by an `@JoinColumn`, you can't do things like b.a.id in a query to access the id for A from inside B. They have a `@QueryInit` annotation to use in those situations where we need to have deeper paths but the docs are very brief and I don't understand how its used. Right now Im getting an "invalid path" exception when I try to run the query inside my application. Has anyone use `@QueryInit` to fix a problem similar to mine ?

The query where clause (ie. in QueryDSL) is something like `a.id.eq(b.a.id)` where a is "embedded" inside b

The exception Im seeing is:

```
"org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'b.a.id' [select a from A a where a.id is not null and (a.id = b.a.id and a.amount <= sum(b.amount))]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'b.a.id' [select a from A a where a.id is not null and (a.id = b.a.id and a.amountCents <= sum(b.amountCents))]",
```

The query Im trying to "translate" into QueryDSL looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM A a
  WHERE a.amount <= (SELECT SUM(b.amount) FROM B b WHERE b.a_id=a.id);
```

Comment: QueryDSL doesn't throw "invalid path" exceptions. Uninitialized paths will lead into null pointer exceptions. Are you sure that the query you're trying to generate is valid by the means of your query language? What is the full stack trace you're getting?

Comment: Yes, I did not say what the exception actually was but I have now edited my question and added the actual error above.

Comment: I also added the SQL query Im trying to write in QueryDSL - quite possible something is being lost in translation.

"a.id.eq(b.a.id).and(a.amount.loe(e.amount.sum()))"

Comment: There are two issues with this query that need to be resolved: (1) you can't reference properties from `b` , if its not one of the join nodes. `b`  needs to be added to the FROM clause or joined first. (2) you cannot use sum(x) in the where clause, and its currently rendered there. Obviously something goes wrong with the subquery. Could you show you're full query builder (the querydsl code)

Comment: Im building a dynamic query so Im basically using BooleanBuilder to build up a predicate so its just the expression (and Im working in Kotlin):

`val a = QA.a`
`val b = QB.b`
`val predicate = BooleanBuilder()`
`...`
`predicate.and(a.id.eq(b.a.id).and(a.amount.loe(b.amount.sum())))`


I need a subquery with a sum on records selected by a condition and then compare that total with the amounts in the table Im trying to pull records from. I don't understand how subqueries work in QueryDSL.

Thanks for looking at this BTW :-)

Answer (score 0):

The predicate ended up simply being:

```
a.amount.loe(
JPAExpressions.select(b.amount.sum()).from(b).where(a.id.eq(b.a.id)))
)
```